# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'coin_user.symbol' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

We have three models (user - currencies - balances) What should be the relationship of these tables, for example, I want to receive the amount of bitcoin currency of user
To do this, I have written the code as follows (according to the help I received from the previous question)

this is user table :

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->enum('type', [User::TYPE_ADMIN, User::TYPE_USER])->default(User::TYPE_USER);
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('password_changed_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

coin table:

```
 Schema::create('coins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('symbol')->unique();
        $table->decimal('buy_percent',6,4)->nullable();
        $table->enum('buy_status' , ['active' , 'inactive'])->default('inactive');
        $table->text('buy_description')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('sell_percent',6,4)->nullable();
        $table->enum('sell_status' , ['active' , 'inactive'])->default('inactive');
        $table->text('sell_description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and balances table. i include pivot table in this migration:

```
        Schema::create('balances', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('coin_id');
            $table->string('symbol');
            $table->decimal('balance');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('coin_user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('coin_id');
            $table->foreign('coin_id')->references('id')->on('coins')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

And relationships are written that way:

in User model :

```
    public function coins() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Coin::class)->withPivot(['symbol', 'balance']);
    }
```

in Coin model :

```
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot(['symbol', 'balances']);
    }
```

and Balance model :

```
    public function coins()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Coin::class , 'balances');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(User::class , 'balances');
    }
```

when i run this code:

```
    $coin = Coin::with('users')->get();
    foreach ($coin as $coin) {
        // $coin here is `BTC`, `ETH`, etc.
        foreach ($coin->users as $user) {
            // $user here is Bob, Mike, etc.
            $user->pivot->balance; // 0.16, etc.
            // Do whatever with `$coin` and `$user`
        }
    }
```

this error returned for me:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'coin_user.symbol' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `coin_user`.`coin_id` as `pivot_coin_id`, `coin_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `coin_user`.`symbol` as `pivot_symbol`, `coin_user`.`balances` as `pivot_balances` from `users` inner join `coin_user` on `users`.`id` = `coin_user`.`user_id` where `coin_user`.`coin_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)

What is the problem? How can I access users' balances?

Comment: *"according to the help I received from the previous question"* - The help you received from the previous question said that your table approach is not valid with `belongsToMany()`... Also, didn't see you in the chat you requested, figured you'd ping again if you had some more follow-up 

Comment: I'm very sorry..I thought you did not see the chat request and I felt my question was too long because I created a new question.
And I apologize for the negligence. I did not mean that. I just can not good speak and understand English well. I do not understand what you mean by `is not valid with belongsToMany ()` @TimLewis

Comment: No worries, I figured that was the case. Just for housekeeping purposes, having the same question opened twice is not great (probably can just delete the old one to be honest). And by "not valid with", I mean that `belongsToMany()` doesn't work with a pivot table that is a pivot between 3 models (Coin, Balance and User). The code you used above could work with 3 tables/2 models, `coins`, `users` and `balances`, and `Coin` and `User` (with some tweaking), but since you added `balances` as a Model and `coin_user` as another pivot, it's not valid.

Comment: Sure. I will delete it.So what is the solution, what should I do? @TimLewis

Comment: Either rethink your table structure (have `balances` be the pivot between `users` and `coins`, with a column `balance` to keep track of the balance), or adjust your models and relationships to not use `belongsToMany()`, but rather `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()`, etc.

Comment: bro, I do not understand, can you explain with a code? (im so sorry ) @TimLewis

Comment: Not really, no... I only have so much room to work with/time to help with this; I can't possibly explain the differences between a `one-to-many` and a `many-to-many` relationship, database normalization, Model/Relationships in Laravel, etc etc; you'll have to do your research on those topics and come up with the best approach that fits your requirements... Sorry...

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel, if two models are to have `belongsToMany` relationship, then a pivot table has to exist for the two models. The absence of a pivot table (assumed so as you did not provide any pivot table schema in your question) is the number one problem here.